# Inserting many similar records into MySQL efficiently

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert many (from tens to hundreds) of similar records into one table in one "transaction". The records only differ by primary key and one more field. The table is a MEMORY table and the inserted records are very often UPDATED and often DELETED, but some can stay in the table for a day. The table structure:

```
id     BIGINT
sid    CHAR
pid    INT
mask   INT
param1 INT
param2 INT
...    INT
paramN INT

PRIMARY (id, sid),
KEY [BTREE] (sid), (param1), (param2), (...), (paramN)
```

Right now the inserts happen through a prepared statement:

```
INSERT INTO object_subscriptions (id, sid, pid, mask, ...)
    VALUES (:id, :sid, :pid, :mask, ...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mask = mask | VALUES(mask)
```

Sample records:

```
13194140000467 | 'fBF8OfQlAjSS8uXsAAzx' | 7 | 22 |    3 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 1
18392199238192 | 'fBF8OfQlAjSS8uXsAAzx' | 7 | 22 |    3 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 1
26342478965721 | 'fBF8OfQlAjSS8uXsAAzx' | 7 | 22 |    3 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 1
64322445645318 | 'fBF8OfQlAjSS8uXsAAzx' | 7 | 22 |    3 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 1
13194140000467 | 'n2pFykYGNnsp-JfCAeJO' | 5 | 97 | 1293 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 0
18392199238192 | 'n2pFykYGNnsp-JfCAeJO' | 5 | 97 | 1293 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 0
26342478965721 | 'n2pFykYGNnsp-JfCAeJO' | 5 | 97 | 1293 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 0
64322445645318 | 'n2pFykYGNnsp-JfCAeJO' | 5 | 97 | 1293 | 0 | 188 | 5123 | 0
```

This works great at tens of records per batch. With hundreds per batch it drastically slow down. An obvious optimization, which can double or triple the performance is to have multiple VALUE sets in one statement, but this still leaves the overhead of sending `N params`, as well as `sid` and `pid` with each record, even though only `id` and `mask` vary in one batch.

I was thinking about including these 'fixed' values in the prepared statement, however these 'params' are generated from user input and are not trusted. I am kind of stuck with MySQL and MEMORY because of how often the data changes and how many index lookups need to be performed. Otherwise I would have normalized the data or moved everything to key-value store.

Comment: Can you write it to a file and use `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: I can think of ways to avoid repeating the common elements, but they end up being pretty verbose, so it may not actually solve the problem.

Comment: @Barmar the overhead of accessing the filesystem may be too much for batches with only a few tens of records. Regardless, the MySQL server may or may not be on the localhost, so writing to file is not always an option. Besides, the file itself would have to be read in full, reading all the duplicate values. However, sequential file reading is much faster than shipping prepared statements one-by-one from the external client.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the only way I can think of to avoid repeating the common elements. Unfortunately, it may be so verbose that it's no better than what you're replacing.

```
INSERT INTO object_subscriptions (id, sid, pid, mask, ...)
SELECT t1.id, t2.sid, t2.pid, t1.mask, ...
FROM (SELECT :id1 id, :mask1 mask
      UNION
      SELECT :id2, :mask2
      UNION
      SELECT :id3, :mask3
      ...
    ) t1
JOIN (SELECT :sid sid, :pid pid, ...) t2
```

This just does one batch. To do multiple batches in a single query, you can add a `UNION` to the top-level `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO object_subscriptions (id, sid, pid, mask, ...)
SELECT t1.id, t2.sid, t2.pid, t1.mask, ...
FROM (SELECT :batch1_id1 id, :batch1_mask1 mask
      UNION
      SELECT :batch1_id2, :batch1_mask2
      UNION
      SELECT :batch1_id3, :batch1_mask3
      ...
    ) t1
JOIN (SELECT :batch1_sid sid, :batch1_pid pid, ...) t2
UNION
SELECT t1.id, t2.sid, t2.pid, t1.mask, ...
FROM (SELECT :batch2_id1 id, :batch2_mask1 mask
      UNION
      SELECT :batch2_id2, :batch2_mask2
      UNION
      SELECT :batch2_id3, :batch2_mask3
      ...
    ) t1
JOIN (SELECT :batch2_sid sid, :batch2_pid pid, ...) t2
UNION
...
```

Comment: Wow. I have to say, this is impressive. By the looks of it, all the extra SELECTs and UNIONs will still be shorter than sending all the params with each query. Definitely worth the try, especially in a large latency situations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi-row insert:

```
INSERT INTO object_subscriptions (id, sid, pid, mask, ...)
    VALUES (:id[0], :sid[0], :pid[0], :mask[0], ...),
  (:id[1], :sid[1], :pid[`], :mask[1], ...), ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mask = mask | VALUES(mask)
```

This will cut down on the client-server back and forth traffic and allow MySQL to use some internal bulk-load optimizations.

Comment: he mentioned that in his question. The problem is all the repetitions of the same values in each row.